# Transformation of 3 values to [0->100] scale

Tags: math

I'm having trouble finding a transformation that adheres to the following criteria:

1. The 3 input numbers can be negative, positive, or 0
2. The scale is unknown for a single trio of numbers, however, I could scan through the data to find the min and max values for the entire data-set, if that helps.
3. The 3 output numbers must be between 0 and 100 (inclusive) and sum up to 150, with 50 being the 'new zero'. So for 3 input numbers of 0, 0, 0, the output would be 50, 50, 50. Negative numbers would end up below 50 (but >= 0), and positive numbers would end up above 50 (but <= 100).

Here are two real examples of input numbers:

- -19, 253, -267
- -479, 137, -179

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assume you have input numbers `10, 10, 10`. Your third requirement states that the output numbers must be `> 50`. But at the same time, they are supposed to sum to `150`. How is that possible? If you have two negative values (any value) and one positive, would then `49, 49, 52` be a valid solution? And similar for one negative and two positive; and one negative, one zero, one positive.

Comment: You mention "three numbers" and then "the entire dataset". What is the relationship between the three numbers and the dataset?

Comment: I think you're right Nico, I have to drop the 'sum to 150' requirement.

Comment: I could also define the sum of the 3 numbers, then divide each number by the sum. With those 3 values, I could re-add the 'sum to 150' requirement, no?

For example, for: -19, 253, -267, they'd sum to -33, and their portions would be: 0.575, -7.504, 7.929 (each number divided by -33), now summing up to 1.

Comment: Stef, I have thousands of these trios of numbers. I'm not sure there is any direct relationship between the trios. But I do have access to the entire dataset, so I could find min, max, etc.